# json_decode() does not work with this valid JSON string

Tags: php, json, escaping, postmark

Here is the JSON string my app is receiving from Postmark, an inbound email delivery service:

```
{
  "From": "me@mydomain.com",
  "FromFull": {
    "Email": "me@mydomain.com",
    "Name": "Jack"
  },
  "To": "\"test@email.mydomain.com\" <test@email.mydomain.com>",
  "ToFull": [
    {
      "Email": "test@email.mydomain.com",
      "Name": "test@email.mydomain.com"
    }
  ],
  "Cc": "",
  "CcFull": [],
  "ReplyTo": "",
  "Subject": "Brussel Sprouts",
  "MessageID": "a97fb074-338e-48c5-97db-d9c5155e9307",
  "Date": "Sun, 30 Dec 2012 18:10:54 +0000",
  "MailboxHash": "",
  "TextBody": "Are Nice",
  "HtmlBody": "",
  "Tag": "",
  "Headers": [
    {
      "Name": "X-Spam-Checker-Version",
      "Value": "SpamAssassin 3.3.1 (2010-03-16) onrs-iad-pm-inbound1.wildbit.com"
    },
    {
      "Name": "X-Spam-Status",
      "Value": "No"
    },
    {
      "Name": "X-Spam-Score",
      "Value": "0.0"
    },
    {
      "Name": "X-Spam-Tests",
      "Value": "RCVD_IN_DNSWL_BLOCKED"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Received-SPF",
      "Value": "None (no SPF record) identity=mailfrom; client-ip=209.85.212.175; helo=mail-wi0-f175.google.com; envelope-from=me@mydomain.com; receiver=test@email.mydomain.com.com"
    },
    {
      "Name": "X-Google-DKIM-Signature",
      "Value": "v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed\/relaxed;        d=google.com; s=20120113;        h=x-received:from:content-type:content-transfer-encoding:subject         :message-id:date:to:mime-version:x-mailer:x-gm-message-state;        bh=JrLpPQqTnp0QixED2qZ5+zepXQXuPLJWqihFECt8uJ4=;        b=EJHac6BaGi3laxnMZZ3Lf\/ervtavKTG0+DHXRRCfGH2HSG42wN\/qIj6IQ0G36NFsjT         x2tnYRhj7aBRseky+YEyAF99kUOx\/p8qaCWo7wN1cf3dTJUrrQu\/vrdgdXezfheKW49z         x4\/d\/8f2bgJN5MvTtZj15WmqZRCDt8\/QJVZvP7J5hANdxqULgwAJCaCJFU3CTNu66nT+         M1tPSDfZwTdNsS70Pna75Y3bRtlJPxXF6gesYhXK\/cnDbqsCopcAiEc9guMVMnqAjIRu         XqBWLft4Bom5H2ViNj5V\/A3GCmP44h\/OM1h+h2zBTYJ3fJK4zyluok8K5GIjn9KN1o2w         v4eA=="
    },
    {
      "Name": "X-Received",
      "Value": "by 10.180.72.146 with SMTP id d18mr51711599wiv.33.1356891056971;        Sun, 30 Dec 2012 10:10:56 -0800 (PST)"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Content-Transfer-Encoding",
      "Value": "7bit"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Message-Id",
      "Value": "<224B85F9-B9C2-4273-A81C-7C340E8A66B2@mydomain.com>"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Mime-Version",
      "Value": "1.0 (Mac OS X Mail 6.2 \\(1499\\))"
    },
    {
      "Name": "X-Mailer",
      "Value": "Apple Mail (2.1499)"
    },
    {
      "Name": "X-Gm-Message-State",
      "Value": "ALoCoQl0eQmrBNRNbe7T06oTeDXcEA3LDLJurR2U0Yj64EyOA2Iy3YL6CyiTodGXtuJHIuMlm5a1"
    }
  ],
  "Attachments": []
}
```

Copy that into any JSON Validator and you'll see that it is valid.

However, when I run `json_decode();` on this string in PHP, it fails silently. When running `echo json_last_error();` the returned error code is `4`. This corresponds to a Syntax Error.

By simply find-replacing `\` to `\\` in my code editor, I can get this to work, but how can I get PHP to automatically do this?

**EDIT:** As discovered in the comments, the exact string I posted above works correctly when read in from a file, as PHP does not try to parse any backslashes etc. However, it appears to be parsing the slashes when read in from `file_get_contents('php://input)` which is what is now causing me problems.

Comment: How do you get the string into the variable that you then run `json_decode()` on? Put it in a file *blah* and try `json_decode(file_get_contents('blah'))`. See if it fails, too.

Comment: On the live site, I receive it via `file_get_contents('php://input')`. At the moment I am simply using a hardcoded string whilst trying to debug this. (Edit: just saw your edit. Isn't this the same thing?)

Comment: It works fine if you load *that* string from a file. This implies that the string is different in your test where it fails. You can inspect your string with `echo $str` to see the difference.

Comment: Where are you doing the string validation?

Comment: If you use a hardcoded string, you need to add the backslashes because they are removed when the PHP file is loaded. That's why I suggested `file_get_contents()` which reads the file as-is (leaves backslashes alone completely).

Comment: @AndreKR got it - `file_get_contents()` parses it correctly. Going to re-try now with actual data from Postmark. Will update in a second.

Comment: OK, update - reading the string from a file works. However - receiving the string via `file_get_contents('php://input')` does not. It fails silently again. Any ideas why...?

Comment: So it's reading the string from STDIN. How do you put it in there? Like this? `php your_script.php < blah`?

Answer (score 5):

You could do this on the variable:

```
$json = str_replace('\\', '\\\\', $json);
```

Comment: It's backslashes I'm having trouble with.

Comment: The problem now is that your edited code produces a syntax error in PHP - because the backslash escapes the `'`. This is where I'm getting stuck too :-(

Comment: Jesus christ, sorry, now I have escaped all the backslashes too. So many unnecessary down votes...