# Need to keep backslashes in JSON feed when parsing in PHP

Tags: php, json, parsing

here is an example of one of our JSON feeds:

```
{"wiggins": {
  "id": "bkstir-04380-wdr-q",
  "alertcolour": "yellow",
  "infohvr": "",
  "infoclk": "",
  "warning": "10",
  "warnhvr": "There are 10 files stuck in \\server.domain.co.uk\Country\Dept\Output",
  "warnclk": "\\server.domain.co.uk\Country\Dept\Output",
  "process": "abc-app-015 Spooler",
  "processhvr": "",
  "processclk": "http://xyz-abc-001.svr.domain.co.uk/monitors/39.html"
}}
```

the backslashes are stopping the php from displaying it, if I have a JSON without any backslashes in it then they display fine, however I need the slashes in there as the person displaying the page needs to go to the link. To get it working for now I've also tried `stipslashes()` but it doesn't work. Can anyone offer any advise? thanks. This is the code parsing the files (as I say, this bit works as long as there are no backslashes):

```
$path = "../../Admins/VBScript/Monitors/JSON/"; //where JSONs are stored
foreach (glob($path."*.json") as $file){ //loop through each file
$json = file_get_contents($file); //get JSON files
$data = json_decode($json, true); //parse the file
```

The JSON files come back as valid on sites I've tested them on.

Comment: does \\ disappears too? or they are appearing as one '\' ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your JSON is not valid. Backslashes have to be escaped like this:

```
{"wiggins": {
  "id": "bkstir-04380-wdr-q",
  "alertcolour": "yellow",
  "infohvr": "",
  "infoclk": "",
  "warning": "10",
  "warnhvr": "There are 10 files stuck in \\\\server.domain.co.uk\\Country\\Dept\\Output",
  "warnclk": "\\\\server.domain.co.uk\\Country\\Dept\\Output",
  "process": "abc-app-015 Spooler",
  "processhvr": "",
  "processclk": "http://xyz-abc-001.svr.domain.co.uk/monitors/39.html"
}}
```

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14093445/json-decode-does-not-work-with-this-valid-json-string) you could use

```
$json = str_replace('\\', '\\\\', $json);
```

to fix your JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON data is not considered valid JSON according to the standards in place. Using [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) your data throws parser errors until all slashes are escaped. You can read this standard here: 
[JSON Data Standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf)
 The information above is on page 4 and requires forward and backward solidus characters to be escaped. JSON_ENCODE() and JSON_DECODE() will take care of the removal of the escapes as well so your formatting for an HTML link should be valid.