# dont want python to remove the backslash '\' when loaded from a json file

Tags: python, json

when i load a json file on python

```
"query": "{\"find\": \"terms\", \"field\": \"TEST_CASE\"}",
```

is changed to

```
'query': '{"find": "terms", "field": "TEST_CASE"}',
```

im not bothered about the type of quotes but i want the '\' backslash to be present at the appropriate place.im loading the json file like this

```
json_data=open(json_file)
data = json.load(json_data)
```

Comment: Don't try and remove the backslash - that's impossible. Instead, try to realize the truth: there is no backslash.

Comment: Why do you want to remove the backlashes? Do you want the keys to have values like `\"find\"` rather than `find`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need to keep backslashes in JSON feed when parsing in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700909/need-to-keep-backslashes-in-json-feed-when-parsing-in-php)

Comment: @tigerhawk The OP wants to preserve the backslashes, not remove them.

Comment: I find it a little odd that the `"query"` value is a string and not a proper JSON object (which would become a `dict` when converted to Python).

Answer (score 1):

The `\` character is called an `escape character`, which interprets the character following it differently.

A backslash needs to be escaped with another backslash.So if you want to escape your backslash,you should replace `\` with `\\`.

Comment: That's true for string literals inside python code but not for reading from a json file.  json.load doesn't like it.

Comment: In the json file, escape the " with 3 back slashes, e.g. \\\" .